# CGridView to display data from two tables?

Tags: yii

I'd like to set up a CGridView. I'm looking to display data from 2 different tables in one view. The data is from a table called student, and another table called employee.

employee is refereed by student(reg_no)

### student table

reg_no (primary key)
s_name
dept
f_name

### employee table

e_no(primary key)
e_name
desig
salary
reg_no(foreign key)

I want to display the (reg_no,s_name,f_name) from student and (design,salary) from employee table in a single grid view, can anyone please give an idea or any tutorial,

Comment: you can review this entry
is very useful http://www.mrsoundless.com/post/2011/05/09/Searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-CGridView.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First make sure that your models and relationships are defined properly. Check the models to make sure that relationships are there.
e.g. you shall have an entry like this in your employee model;

```
function relations() {
    return array(
        'reg_no'=>array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'reg_no' ),
    );
}
```

Use CActiveDataProvider in the CGridView instead of an array as the data source.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$model->searchEmplyees(),
 .......
 .......
```

Add another search cirteria to your model that returns the data as a CActiveDataProvider.

```
public function seachEmployees()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'i';
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    .......
            ....... 
    $criteria->join= 'JOIN 'your table name' d ON (i.id=d.id)';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'order_in_sna ASC',
        ),
    ));
}
```

I have just typed this code in for your reference so you understand how Yii is handling all of this for you. [This is another good example, again from the Yii Framework site](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/).